# Increase Memory of opencascade project

Tags: visual-c++, opencascade

My opencascade project is built in visual c++ environment. My problem is that when I try to run the program there is an error as, "Fatal Error in graphic initialization."
Can I use a bat file and set the memory allocation using it and how? Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Opencascade is a bit on the whiney side when it comes to setting it up.

In $OCCTinstallation\ros, there lives a batch file called env.bat, which sets up all required environment variables for Occt to work.

Alternatively, you could set these Environment variables in your system's settings. From the Error message you posted my guess would be that adding this to your Environment block should do the Trick:

```
set CSF_GraphicShr=%CASROOT%\win32\bin\TKOpenGl.dll
```

Yes, OCCT does need to be told where to look for it's opengl wrapper library by an environment var. if CASROOT is not defined on your system (should be after an installation of OCCT), this conatinas the location of the subfolder $occtInstallation\ros.

Since OCCT is not in widespread use, you might consider to register at the [offical OCCT-forum](http://www.opencascade.org/org/forum/) for more specific questions concerning its functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. But it did not solve my issue. :( I have already registered in the forum, but did not get any response to my question.